# Moving files between accounts on a Mac

Tags: osx-lion, login

I did something bad and killed my wife's login on her Early 2008 MB/10.7.5. Any attempt to log into that account crashes back to the login screen. Other accounts work fine.

I created a new account so she could get up and running, but of course all her documents/music/pictures are missing.

I'd like to move all those files. The typical suggestion uses the DropBox, but requires you to log into the original account - which I can't. So I'm looking for more techy solutions.

I'm sure a mv and chown will do this. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as soon as you log into her old account. That will logon in safe mode. If that works, you can try to find out what the problem with the account is (Preference file corruption - use something like Preferential Treatment http://www.jonn8.com/html/pt.html or corrupt file permissions - use Disk Utility) or just move all the files out of that account and into the new one.

Comment: That did work, thanks! Now is there any way to look for pref pane conflicts?

Comment: @user1469457 Updated answer with additional information